# Beginner question regarding Linear Algebra. (Concept of orthogonal directions in a square matrix?)

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

**Disclaimer:**

I realize that this is very much a beginner question, and probably not the most interesting question for the audience of this forum, but I don't know where else to ask it, so please bear with me..

I am trying to read-up on/study the material I need to understand in order to solve this challenge that I'm facing, but I don't know the right terms, or even if what I am looking for exists, so I am mainly here hoping that someone can give me some pointers, and perhaps tell me whether what I am trying to do is possible/feasible or whether what I am doing will lead me down a dead end.

**Background:**

I have written my own (simple) spice simulator in Python using MNA (Modified Nodal Analysis), which is a linear-algebra method for solving electrical systems.

MNA results in a matrix equation of the form;

$$[\boldsymbol{G}]\boldsymbol{V}=\boldsymbol{I_s}$$

Where;

$ [\boldsymbol{G}] $ is called the Conductance-Matrix, and it "describes" the circuit.

$ \boldsymbol{V} $ is a vector of unknown node voltages and branch currents.

$ \boldsymbol{I_s} $ is a vector containing the independent sources (voltage/current sources)

MNA makes it "easy" to solve for the unknown node voltages and branch currents by inverting the conductance matrix and multiplying it on to $ \boldsymbol{I_s} $ as follows;

$$ \boldsymbol{V} = [\boldsymbol{G}]^{-1}\boldsymbol{I_s} $$

What I want to do now boils down to this;

I want to try to optimize (numerically) the values chosen for the component values of the circuit, to get the resulting transfer function to fit a dataset that I have (which comes from FEM).

I have found from experimentation that this is actually easy enough to do if you completely ignore the complexity of the problem, and just brute force your way through thousands of possible component values.

But I am not really satisfied with this solution as I fully realize that it is a very inefficient solution. One reason for this is that you can create many very different circuits (with different component values) which would all result in exactly the same conductance matrix, and hence give exactly the same result, this means that when I am just trying different component values I might actually very well be trying the same (or almost the same) conductance matrix multiple times without even knowing it.

**Question:**

So what I would like to know is this;

1) Is there such a concept as "orthogonal-directions/unit-vectors" when it comes to matrices? Ie. is it possible to find a smallest number of different matrices that combined in different proportions give all possible variations over a certain conductance matrix? such that I can be certain that changing one of these proportions will change the conductance matrix in a way which is different from the way changing any of the others would?

(That was quite a mouthful I know, but without knowing the right lingo it is hard to be more concise).

I sincerely hope that someone will find it in them to point me in the right direction, rather than just giving me nonsense about how I don't know enough about what I'm asking, or that this question doesn't belong on this forum and that I need to get lost..

**Note:**

It is fully intentional from my side that I have not gone into detail about how MNA works, because it would have made this question many pages long, but it is all explained very simply in the articles linked to below (it's a very quick read).

I am reading from the following articles on MNA; [1](http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/vlsi/_media/courses/ee2015_2017/mna.pdf) [2](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781119078388.app2) [3](https://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/mna/MNA3.html)

**EDIT!:**

This is the conductance matrix of a simple RC-circuit (resistor-capacitor circuit);

```
⎡ 1/R        -1/R          1⎤
⎢                           ⎥
⎢-1/R       C⋅s + 1/R      0⎥
⎢                           ⎥
⎣  1           0           0⎦
```

One of the answers stated that the rows and columns of the matrix could be thought of as directions, but how should I understand this? as in scaling a row or column by a scalar?

The problem with that is that if you look at the example matrix above; How would you scale any one row or column? since the resistor R contributes to both two top rows and both of the first columns, scaling any one of those rows or columns would result in a matrix which no longer represents a real world circuit.

Comment: I don't know what answer are you looking for. Yes, these things exist, but to implement them you will need to understand linear algebra.

Comment: @Orenio yes I know that I will have to understand a lot more linear algebra than I do at the moment to be able to implement this, that doesn't worry me at all, it wouldn't be the first time I have studied advanced subjects like this on my own. The answer I am looking for is "Yes that exists, it is called; blablabla..." or better; "Yes that exists, you need to read up on; bla bla, and bla bla and bla bla.".. I consider it irrelevant whether you believe that I can learn this on my own or not, let that be my problem. Just point me in the right direction please, if you can..

Comment: Try looking at inner product spaces. That should bring you closer to topics of orthogonality and orthogonal bases (Gram-Schmidt process). Hope that helps.

Comment: @Orenio Thank you very much for that, that was exactly the kind of inputs I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a matrix then you have rows and columns.  Now a matrix does not necessarily have anything to do with "geometry" but we can take the rows and columns as defining directions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, that actually makes a lot of sense to me, but is it really that easy/simple? It seems logical enough that it would be that way.. What I don't understand about this is that when constructing the conductance matrix each element contributes to two rows and to two columns (unless one end is grounded), so just intuitively it would seem to me that if you were to just scale the rows and columns then you could end up with components that have a different value at one node that the other (which is not possible in the real world)..

Comment: ..I have added an example to my question, it is obvious from this example that scaling any rows or columns would result in a circuit which is no longer valid.